# How to plot a function in Julia

Tags: function, plot, julia

I would like to log plot a function in Julia.

```
using Plots 
x = 1:100

plot(x.^2, xaxis=:log)
```

[image]

I used the same logic as the working code from above but I got following error:
My guess is that I need to "transform" the function into a unit range (if that makes any sense). However, I am not sure how to do that.

```
using Plots
function test(a)
    alpha = 1
    for i in 1:a
        alpha += 1
    end
    return alpha
end
   
a = 1:100
plot(test(a), xaxis=:log)

MethodError: no method matching (::Colon)(::Int64, ::UnitRange{Int64})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to broadcast `test` like this:

```
plot(test.(a), xaxis=:log)
```

(note a `.` after `test`)

Alternatively `plot` is smart enough to know how to plot a function just like this:

```
plot(test, 1, 100, xaxis=:log)
```

See [here](http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/input_data/#Functions) for more examples.